# How to show only a view

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I am new to RCP and perhaps the question is basic but:
in perspective with two views, how can one show only one of them at the beginning of the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    public class Perspective implements IPerspectiveFactory {

        /** Top folder's id. */
        public static final String FI_TOP = Bootstrap.PLUGIN_ID + ".topFolder";
        /** Top folder's id. */
        public static final String FI_BOTTOM = Bootstrap.PLUGIN_ID+ ".bottomFolder";

        float ratioTop = 0.35f;
        float ratioBottom = 0.60f;

        private IPageLayout layout;

        public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) {
            this.layout = layout;

            String editorAreaId = layout.getEditorArea();
            layout.setEditorAreaVisible(false);

            layout.createPlaceholderFolder(FI_TOP, IPageLayout.TOP, ratioTop, editorAreaId);
            layout.createPlaceholderFolder(FI_BOTTOM, IPageLayout.BOTTOM, ratioBottom, editorAreaId);

            //Opnen a view
            layout.addView("MyViewId", IPageLayout.TOP, 0.9f, layout.getEditorArea());

        }

        public IPageLayout getLayout() {
            return layout;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Luiz for the quick response and forgive my ignorance but what does it mean bootstrap?

Comment: oh sorry. Bootstrap is my activator class. Bootstrap extends the AbstractUIPlugin class

Comment: Hi Luiz, it´s possible the user select an item from the table in viewA and that selection open viewB which at the beginning is hidden?

Comment: please, open another question.